# checking if characters are equal to a word

Tags: java, class, methods, character

```
 do {            
            System.out.println("Word: " + secretWord.getWordMask());
            //System.out.print("Guesses: " + guesses);
            System.out.print("Enter your guess: ");
            Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
            String guess = keyboard.next();

            WordHider revealChar = new WordHider();

            revealChar.revealLetter(guess);
            System.out.println(revealChar.getWordMask());
            secretWord.revealLetter(guess);


    } while ();
```

what my code does now is continuously ask the user for a letter, then revelas it if its part of the word. I have another method in a different class that checks to see if the hidden word is found or not

```
public boolean isHiddenWordFound() {
    for (int i = 0; i < wordMask.length(); i++) {
        if(wordMask.charAt(i) == HIDE_CHAR.charAt(0)) {
            return false;
```

and i need to figure out how to make the `while` part check for that. But i am simply at a loss, any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If isHiddenWordFound says that the file is not found if part of it is hidden, then you need to inverse it to be true to continue the loop, once the word is found it will return true at which point the inverse will be false allowing the program execution to continue:

```
while (!isHiddenWordFound());
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems the isHiddenWordFound method is there for precisely this purpose.

```
do {   
    ...
} while (!isHiddenWordFound());
```